# How do Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message in OS X

Tags: apache-http-server, macos-mojave

I'm getting this error message when starting Apache. I'm using macOS Mojave 10.14.5.

> AH00558: httpd: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using Stevens-MacBook-Air.local. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message httpd (pid 856) already running

I added the name server in the `httpd.conf` file but still am coming up with this error message.

```
# If your host doesn't have a registered DNS name, enter its IP address here.
#
#ServerName www.example.com:80
#ServerName localhost:8080
```

What am I missing that this message still appears?

Comment: Please do not post screenshots of configs. Post the relevant content from the config as code text so it’s easier to read and search. I have gone ahead and added the relevant config lines as text.

Answer (score 1):

> I added the name server in the httpd.conf file but still am coming up with this error message.

Sorry to say but no, you didn’t. This is effectively what you have:

```
# If your host doesn't have a registered DNS name, enter its IP address here.
#
#ServerName www.example.com:80
#ServerName localhost:8080
```

Note how all of the lines above `#ServerName localhost:8080` have `#` prepended to them. That means they are commented out. Look around that config file; there are other lines that are commented as well as commented out. To make your setting take effect, you need to uncomment it like this.

```
# If your host doesn't have a registered DNS name, enter its IP address here.
#
#ServerName www.example.com:80
ServerName localhost:8080
```

Then restart Apache and you should be able to access that Apache server at `http://localhost:8080` as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Add a line to your fully qualified hostname to the apache configuration:

```
LINE='ServerName www.example.com'
FILE='/etc/apache2/apache2.conf'
grep -qF -- "$LINE" "$FILE" || echo "$LINE" >> "$FILE"
service apache2 restart
```

If your server has no domain, use `localhost` instead